# Laravel - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 application I got this code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_log_activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->string('log_url', 300)->nullable();
        $table->string('log_method', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('log_type', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('subject', 200)->nullable();
        $table->string('subject_hint', 20)->nullable();
        $table->integer('company_id', 11)->nullable();
        $table->string('id_address', 64)->nullable();
        $table->string('agent', 300)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The problem is here:

> $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

user_id is not autoincrement, but I got this error:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one
> auto column and it must be defined as a key")

I've tried several methods, but non is working

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using length with integer. 11 count as an auto increment value

```
$table->integer('company_id', 11)->nullable();
```

Remove the length from it

```
$table->integer('company_id')->nullable();
```

if it is a foreign key then use same as user_id

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->integer('company_id', 11)->nullable();
```

replace with

```
$table->integer('company_id')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

if user_id is foreign key you can use foreign method to define:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_log_activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```